# session_destroy not working after modifying session.save_path (where session data is saved on server)

Tags: php, session

I created a folder on the root of my website where session data is stored outside of the public_html. I did this to make the sessions on my website last longer because I was having a problem where they would time out after 30 minutes. I tried many ways to fix it but nothing worked until I tried the code below. I'm using the following code to create sessions that last a day, and the code stopped the problem of them timing out after 30 minutes:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/home/server/.sessionsData');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400); 
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.cache_expire', 86400);
ini_set('session.name', 'website');

session_start(); // Session ready to go!
```

After making this change, the sessions don't time out after 30 minutes anymore, but I have a new problem where my "logout code" which destroys the sessions is no longer ending the sessions like it used to.The following code is what I'm using to logout and destroy sessions, but it no longer works like it used to:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

header("location: https://website.com");
```

What should I do to make it so that the sessions are destroyed and the corresponding session data that is stored my '/home/server/.sessionsData' folder gets deleted? If I go into the folder and delete the session data file directly, it ends the session in the user's browser.

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Comment: Perhaps your `ini_set()` code, or at least the path changing part, needs to be in your log out script as well.

Comment: It worked! You're exactly right. I added ini_set('session.save_path', '/home/server/.sessionsData'); to my log out script and it fixed it. If you want to answer the question with your comment I will mark it as the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok. I think you will be able to accept the answer if I post it. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments
`Perhaps your ini_set() code, or at least the path changing part, needs to be in your log out script as well.`

In code form:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/home/server/.sessionsData');
session_start();
session_destroy();

header("location: https://website.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `session_unset` along with `session_destroy`, is an effective means of actually clearing out SESSION data.

```
session_start();
session_unset(); //--> frees all session variables currently registered.
session_destroy(); //--> destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.
```

I have also read on PHP manual comments the following can help in stubborn browsers:

```
session_write_close(); //--> End the current session and store session data.
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);  //--> replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added in those extra lines.